# c# Uploading files to sharepoint (2 questions)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, upload

I have created a webservice that can upload files to my sharepoint site library. Here is the code I have so far:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string getLibraries(byte[] contents, String destUrl){
            String message = "1";
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                message = "2";
                EnsureParentFolder(site, destUrl);

                site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);
                message = "3";
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            });
            return message;
        }
```

This is working at the moment. But in sharepoint you can add new columns in a library. Like if you would like to add a description of the file or something.

> How do I upload those extra columns with the file?

Another thing I am trying to figure out:
Right now it uploads files under the name `"System account"`. I have tried setting the credentials of the webservice to the credentials of the client app but it didn't change it.

> How do I change this to the login of the user who is using the webservice?

example: file uploaded by `myDomain/User1`

thanks
-Gen-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string getLibraries(byte[] contents, String destUrl, string description){
            String message = "1";
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl).OpenWeb();
                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                message = "2";
                EnsureParentFolder(site, destUrl);

                site.Files.Add(destUrl, contents);
                message = "3";

                SPListItem listItem = site.GetListItem(destUrl);
                listItem["Description"] = description;
                listItem.Update();

                site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            });
            return message;
        }
```

Comment: @wk: Like Tom mentions below, you aren't disposing `SPWeb site`. You need to dispose *at least* the `new SPSite(destUrl)` and also the SPWeb from `OpenWeb()`.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to my second question:

```
SPUserToken token = new SPSite(destUrl).RootWeb.EnsureUser(userName).UserToken;
SPWeb site = new SPSite(destUrl, token).OpenWeb();
```

Comment: where are you planning to populate userName?

Comment: You're not disposing your SPSite (and optionally but recommended also SPWeb) objects -> memory leak

Comment: @Russell: I just wanted the field "last modified by" to display the correct username